# Input fields in responsive table not wide enough

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have a form that contains four input fields that accept the number of questions to be picked in four difficulty levels (*Easy*, *Medium*, *Hard*, *Very Hard*).  However, these questions are:

- of multiple types (multiple choice, short text, etc.).
- from multiple repositories.

I have used a table within a form to represent these input fields.
Each row contains 4 input fields for the number of questions in each difficulty level for one question type from one repository. Here's what it looks like:

```css
.bg-orange {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Pick Questions</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Repository
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Question Type
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Easy
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Medium
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Hard
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Very Hard
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Unit 1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Multiple Choice Questions
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" value="11">
                            <span class="badge badge-success">36</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control is-valid" value="30">
                            <span class="badge badge-warning">38</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control is-invalid" value="100">
                            <span class="badge text-light bg-orange">36</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" value="12">
                            <span class="badge badge-danger">40</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Unit 1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Short Text Questions
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control is-valid" value="11">
                            <span class="badge badge-success">215</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control">
                            <span class="badge badge-warning">43</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control">
                            <span class="badge text-light bg-orange">56</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control">
                            <span class="badge badge-danger">9</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Unit 2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Multiple Choice Questions
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control is-valid" value="11">
                            <span class="badge badge-success">
                                101
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control is-valid" value="42">
                            <span class="badge badge-warning">
                                42
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control is-invalid" value="42">
                            <span class="badge text-light bg-orange">
                                42
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="form-control" value="100">
                            <span class="badge badge-danger">
                                11
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

<sub>*The numbers on the badges under each input field are the number of available/max questions*</sub>

This looks fine on larger screens. But, on smaller screen sizes, the input fields shrink too much and the input text is not fully visible. This is especially of concern when the Bootstrap validation classes `.is-valid` and `.is-invalid` are added to the input fields as seen above. Wrapping it in a div with `.table-responsive` does not help. How can I prevent the text fields from shrinking too much on smaller screens? This is my primary issue.
Also, is a table the right choice here(this leads to too many rows) or are there better options?

Comment: better to add a min width to the cell

Comment: Agreed, add a min-width to each td, and an overflow-x to the table if necessary.